# Big save vs. big saving

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is there a difference in meaning between "big save" vs. "big saving"?

"[Save big today with Big Save
View all our BIG SAVE specials](https://bigsave.co.za/)"

I asked the question because I think I usually hear people using the second expression. Thank you!

Comment: In what context are they used? I can't imagine how "big saving" would be used, perhaps you mean "big saving*s*?

Comment: A ***big saving*** is a significant reduction in the (economic or figurative) ***price*** of something. The only meaning I can come up with for a ***big save*** is something a goalkeeper in a World Championship penalty shootout might do. A "save" is ***never*** used as a noun in "shopping" contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have seen 'save' replacing 'saving' in informal contexts, such as this American advertisement by Wal-Mart: _Add soothing or rejuvenating aroma to this Tree of Life car essential oil diffuser, keep your car fresh with natural and healthy essential oils. [...] With 20 reusable refill pads, you can change the scent in the car regularly without changing the air freshener itself, which is **a big save** for you._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: But this is a *learner's* site. We shouldn't encourage such obvious "syntactic transgressions". But for all I know, clever folk in Walmart's PR/Advertising department worked on that wording for a long time - I'm in no doubt that the McDonald's ***I'm loving it*** slogan was carefully thought up to be "memorably non-idiomatic".

Comment: Anyway, rest assured I did actually check the full OED before my previous comment, just to make sure. The only noun usages there are the "goal-saving" one I mentioned, and *A kind of herb or medicinal preparation of herbs* (listed as *now rare*).

Comment: Hello, I added a context link, but for some reason it was removed.

Comment: I've retracted my earlier downvote. Thank you for adding the context, the wording and a workable link.

Comment: Thank you as well ~

Comment: From the link provided, it appears that 'save' _is_ used in a shopping context in Zambia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard English the noun 'saving' is used to mean 'an amount of something (often money) that you do not use or spend'.

In informal English, the noun 'saving' may be replaced by the verb 'save' used informally as a noun. This is common in advertisements and social media, and may be found in informal casual conversation.

Good advice to English learners is to use the standard form, especially in written work. Informal usages come later.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your explanations!